# How can I change the directory into which SBT puts test resources?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I want the test-compile action to put the contents of src/test/resources into target/scala_2.8.1/test-classes.

The reason for this is that I'm running SBT with IntelliJ IDEA, which puts the test-classes directory on the classpath when it runs tests.

My logback-test.xml file (configuration for logback logging framework) lives in src/test/resources, and it's not being found during testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but instead shows an the alternative that I use.

I add two new tasks: `prepare` and `test-prepare`.

```
lazy val prepare = task{
  None
} dependsOn (compile, copyResources) describedAs ("Compiles main, copies main resources. Use for the before-action in the idea-sbt-plugin")

lazy val testPrepare = task{
  None
} dependsOn (testCompile, copyResources, copyTestResources) describedAs ("Compiles main and test, copies all resources. Use for the before-action in the idea-sbt-plugin")
```

I then configure the 'before run' SBT action to these. This requires the [idea-sbt-plugin](https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin).

[image]

I use the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) SBT Processor to configure the IntelliJ module setup. This includes `target/scala_2.8.1/[test-]resources` as a dependency.

[image]

Comment: The IDEA build process copies resources to the `classes` and `test-classes` directories, which is annoying because then you end up with two sets of resources.

Answer (score 2):

While there might be a better way of doing it, this should work as well as long as nothing else overrides `testCompile`. Just add the following into your project definition.

```
override lazy val testCompile = testCompileAction dependsOn task {
  import sbt.Process._
  "cp -R src/test/resources/* target/scala_2.8.1/test-classes" ! log
  None
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override lazy val testCompile = testCompileAction dependsOn copyTestResources
override def testResourcesOutputPath = testCompilePath
```

Comment: The only problem with copying test resources into the testCompilePath is that the compiler detects modifications on **every** run, slowing things down considerably.