# How to properly manage logback configrations in development and production using SBT & Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt, slf4j, logback, sbt-assembly

I have a pretty standard Scalatra project using Logback for logging.

Following the [logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) I have added a `logback-test.xml` for my development configuration (logs of debugs), whilst maintaining a production `logback.xml`.

However, in development while using the `xsbt-web-plugin` to run a container with code reloading, my app only seems to pick up the `logback.xml`.

How do I get the desired behavior?:

1. In development mode (`./sbt container:start`) the app uses `logback-test.xml`
2. When assembled into a zip using [SBT-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), exclude the test config.

Currently neither of these seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

You're misusing `logback-test.xml`. It's intended for unit-like tests only and should be placed in `src/test/resources` (which is automatically excluded from prod). To achieve what you want - you may set up path to your `logback-dev.xml` by system property:

```
 javaOptions in container += "-Dlogback.configurationFile=/some/path/logback-dev.xml"
```

This path may be relative. See, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26538449/1809978

In my practice we don't pack `logback.xml` even in prod (it's pointed to some external place) to have ability to change logging configuration ad-hoc.

P.S. If you're also interested about excluding files from sbt-assembly - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27198444/1809978) may help

Comment: Seems like this requires me to be using JVM forking? Is that considered standard practice?

Comment: jvm forking is usually fine for web-plugin. if it's a problem - you can just add `-Dlogback...` to your sbt launcher script or just `System.setProperty(...)` inside your build.sbt/Project.scala. The standard practice (for logback) is moving your logback.xml out - the concrete solution depends on your needs.

Comment: Ok, so I started rearranging things. I moved logback-test.xml to `src/test/resources`. There still seem to be problems, as it isn't picked up when running unit tests. It still seems to be reading from `src/main/resources/logback.xml`. Any ideas?

Comment: So it seems like `sbt test` doesn't put `src/test/resources` on the classpath when it runs tests. This seems to have come up before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755234/how-can-i-change-the-directory-into-which-sbt-puts-test-resources, but I don't seem to be able to fix it in sbt 13.5. I just don't understand SBT enough.

Comment: not sure that it's connected - did you try `sbt test:clean`? How do you run the tests - from Idea or Sbt? Sbt uses `target/scala_XX/xxxxx-test.jar` for tests (is there logback-test inside? Idea uses `target/scala_XX/test-classes` folder - you may try to clean both because sometimes sbt just forgetting to add a file.

Comment: I did run clean. IntelliJ works fine and picks up the right file. I actually made another question with a solid example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555677/why-is-logback-loading-configurations-in-a-different-order-and-ignoring-system-p