# Why is logback loading configurations in a different order and ignoring system properties (SBT)?

Tags: scala, logging, sbt, slf4j, logback

I've been trying to sort out my logging situation ([How to properly manage logback configrations in development and production using SBT & Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538717/how-to-properly-manage-logback-configrations-in-development-and-production-using)), and I've run across a funny problem.

According to the [logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#logback.statusLC), logback checks for `logback-test.xml` before it checks for `logback.xml`.

I have the following files:

- `src/main/resources/logback.xml`
- `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml`

So I figured that when running `sbt test`, it would look to the `logback-test.xml`. This is true in intellij (which manages test execution itself), but does not seem to be true when running from the command line.

I renamed my logback.xml and turned on logback debugging, and here is the output. Clearly it's looking for the files in the reverse order:

```
14:58:21,203 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [/home/rathboma/Projects/personal/beekeeper/src/main/resources/logback.xml]
14:58:21,206 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
14:58:21,206 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:/home/rathboma/Projects/personal/beekeeper/target/scala-2.10/test-classes/logback-test.xml]
```

I'm speculating that it's because the test resources are in the test-classes directory, but I have no idea how to properly fix this.

SECONDLY, supplying `-Dlogback.configurationFile=config/logback-#{environment}.xml` doesn't seem to do anything, it toally ignores it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems like -Dlogback.configurationFile now is /home/.../resources/logback.xml and your property was ignored. How did you specify this property for sbt? could you please show your build.sbt?

Comment: try adding this to your build.sbt :  avaOptions in Test += "-Dlogback.configurationFile=src/main/resources/logback-test.xml"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have any typos as it works with intellij.

Logback will try to load `logback-test.xml` then the groovy one then the normal one see [this](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/4dd08e68321548cd85251ec389f5a832505e1268/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/util/ContextInitializer.java). By try to load I mean it will get the class loader to the class running (should be the test class) and look for it in the resources. Check (by print for example) the path to your resources and verify the xml file is there. sbt by default should make sure your test resources are available during test execution (see [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html)). If you changed your build sbt's unmanaged resources or test task dependencies it might no get copied.

Finally if you still did not find the problem (which would be weird) I believe you should start a clean project to check if the problem persists, if it doesnt you should clean your cache in intellij. Still see a problem? sorry can't help, maybe a problem with your sbt installation or version?